# Javascript Gotcha: Why value does not increment?

Tags: javascript

Why is the value for "o.value" unchanged when changer(o.inc) is called?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/illumine/qbr9xupt/

```
function customobject(){
    this.value = 2;
}

customobject.prototype.inc = function(){
    this.value++;
}

function changer(func){
    func(); 
}

var o = new customobject();
alert(o.value); // o.value = 2

o.inc();
alert(o.value); // o.value = 3

changer(o.inc);
alert(o.value); // Still 3 why not 4
```

Comment: Because `this` is not what you think it is. Try `alert(this);` just before `this.value++` and you'll see.

Comment: This page explains what you are experiencing, and also has an example similar to your code.

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
changer(o.inc);
```

You're passing a reference to the `inc` function here. This reference has no association with the `o` object. When you call the function, `this` is this context is the global scope (`window`).

You could bind `o` as `this` to your function before passing it to `changer` like this:

```
changer(o.inc.bind(o));
```

But the `Function.prototype.bind` method isn't supported IE8 and below. A simple alternative solution would be to wrap the function like this:

```
changer(function(){ return o.inc(); });
```

Or alternatively, you could use `Function.prototype.call` to call the function with `o` as `this` and pass a reference to the object.

```
function changer(_this, func){
    func.call(_this);
}
...
changer(o, o.inc);
```

Answer (score 2):

`o.inc` gives you a reference to a function that, when called, does not carry with it the `this` it came from (one of the huge challenges in JS). To work around it, do this:

```
changer(o.inc.bind(o));
```

The `bind` method on a function can cement it to a `this` (as well as do currying if you'd like).

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how `this` behaves is not trivial and very important. I'd recommend taking a look at http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

when calling a method like a regular function, `this` is bound to the `global` object, so `o.inc` doesn't change. You can try this as well:

```
var foo = o.inc;
foo();
console.log(o.value); // still 3
```